# Remove Slug from Custom Post Type

Tags: slug

I was wondering how i can remove the prefix from the slugs of custom post types using htaccess rules or any other appropriate method.

Currently my custom post types look like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/os_estate/5-bedroom-property-for-sale
```

and i would simply like this to be:

```
http://www.domain.com/5-bedroom-property-for-sale
```

I was able to achieve this via a plugin but it significantly added to the page load time..

My common settings in Permalinks is set to "Post Name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simpler and lighter solution:

First: set the slug argument for your custom post type to '/' when registering the post type:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_post_type' );
function register_my_post_type() {
    $args = array(
            //The rest of arguments you are currently using goes here
            'rewrite'    => array(
                             'slug' => '/'
                             )
     );
     register_post_type( 'my-post-type', $args );   
}
```

Second: in `preg_get_posts()` action hook include your post type in the query when only the `$query->query['name']` is present:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_include_my_post_type_in_query' );
function wpse_include_my_post_type_in_query( $query ) {

     // Only noop the main query
     if ( ! $query->is_main_query() )
         return;

     // Only noop our very specific rewrite rule match
     if ( 2 != count( $query->query )
     || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) )
          return;

      // Include my post type in the query
     if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) )
          $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'my-post-type' ) );
 }
```

Third: I've found that in some situations there are conflicts with pages and single posts. I've been able to avoid this conflict by checking if a page with the request name exists and overriding the query conditionals but I'm not sure if more conflict can happens:

```
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpse_parse_query' );
function wpse_parse_query( $wp_query ) {

    if( get_page_by_path($wp_query->query_vars['name']) ) {
        $wp_query->is_single = false;
        $wp_query->is_page = true;
    }

}
```

**IMPORTANT**: You need to flush the rewrite rules. You can do it by viviting the permalink options page in the admin area. This is needed because we are registering a new rewrite rule, so the current rewrite rules stored in the database must be regenerated.

Comment: hmm. I have tested the code but it seems that the whole custom post type disappears when I put its name in your code!

Comment: The permalink is correctly changes to www.domain.com/postname but I do not see the link to edit the post nor I can see this at the backend..

Comment: You have to complete the `$args` for `register_post_type()` function. To make things easier you can just add the argument  `'rewrite'    => array('slug' => '/' )` to your actual register post type implementation and then add the code of the second step to your functions.php theme file or to your plugin file. Note that in the second step you have to add the custom post type names in `$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'my-post-type-1', my-post-type-2', 'etc..' ) );`. If you post your actual code to register the custom post types I can post the full working code.

Comment: ok this works now but it messes up with my pages template sidebar... is it possible to exclude pages from your code?

Comment: If it works, please accept the answer. I don't understand you "new" problem about pages template sidebar. If you exclude pages from my code, URLs like `http://mysite.com/i-am-a-page/` won't work. You will need to load the desired template/sidebar using conditional tags like [is_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page), [is_single()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single) or `[is_singular()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular).

Comment: it doesn't work as such because if i use the code above, my pages from full-width are converted to pages with a sidebar... i have tried excluding 'page' from the $query->set but still the problem persists

Comment: I've tested and the code does exactly what you asked in the question. Are you sure that adding `'rewrite'=> array('slug' => '/')` to your custom post type and adding the `pre_get_posts()` hook posted above is what is causing the problem with the template?

Comment: I forget to say that after the change in the `rewrite` argument of the custom post type, you need to flush the rewrite rules in Wordpress. See edited answer.

Comment: thanks - do i also need to clean the cache or that wouldn't affect it?

Comment: Yes, should clean the cache also.

Comment: i am sorry but i have cleared  the cache and updated permalinks but for some reason my pages all get messed up. The code works fine in terms of doing what is supposed to do but it messes up the templates for the pages. I have tested this three times.

Answer (score 0):

// Well then, first use a function to mention your custom post types.

```
function my_custom_post_types(){
    return array(
        'os_estate', 
        'os_villas', 
        'os_chalets', 
        'os_cottages'
    );
}
```

// Then, filtering the request.

```
    add_action( 'parse_request','my_custom_post_types_parse_request', 999);

function my_custom_post_types_parse_request( $query ){

    if( isset($query->request) )
    {
        $req = explode('/', ltrim($query->request,'/'));
        if( !is_admin() && isset($req['0']) )
        {
            global $wpdb;
            $name = stripslashes($req['0']);
            $_post = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_name ='". $name ."' AND post_type IN ('" . join("', '", my_custom_post_types() ) . "')" );

            if( $_post )
            {
                $query->query_vars['error'] = '';
                $query->query_vars['post_type'] = $_post->post_type;
                $query->query_vars['name'] = $name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// And next filter all the desired post types link.

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'my_custom_post_types_permalink', 10, 2);

function my_custom_post_types_permalink( $post_link, $post ){
    if( in_array( $post->post_type, my_custom_post_types() ) && !empty($post->post_name) && $post->post_status == 'publish' && '' != get_option('permalink_structure') )
    {
        $post_name = $post->post_name;
        $post_link = home_url("/$post_name/");
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```

EDIT: fixed errors, adding this line due to edit 6 chars minimum requirement

Comment: I actually have a lot of custom post types namely os_estate, os_villas, os_chalets, os_cottages - could you please modify your code to include all of them?

Comment: thank you i will test this tomorrow and will let you know how it goes.. I also did notice that i could modify my theme directly.. is your solution in terms of performance and speed adequate?

Comment: Exactly, you can see i am just using one query to find a match within defined custom post types. But if you use empty slug, that will either return 404 error, or if that returns fine, then post (default post type) page will be inaccessible. But with this solution, we leaving the rest of your site as it is. Thanks.

Comment: That extra query you are using is not needed at all if you include the custom post type in the main query. Also, it is not needed to filter the `post_type_link` if you set the slug you want to use during the registration of the custom post type. See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you just need to put rewrite rule in your code in place where you register post type.

Just place this code

```
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                => '',
    'with_front'          => true,
    'pages'               => true,
    'feeds'               => true,
    );
```

after the **$labels array();**

and before **$args = array();**

Comment: This won't work. If you set the `slug = ''` it will be filled with the default value which is the `post_type`.