# Remove parent from custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, theme-development

I've created a new custom post type with WordPress. However, the slug adds the post to a parent, like so:

`http://example.com/UNNCESSARY-PARENT/post-title`

However, I'd like it to create:

`http://example.com/post-title`

Is this possible? This is how I've registered the post type:

```
function create_films() {
  register_post_type( 'films',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Films' ,
        'singular_name' =>  'Films'

      ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag') 
    )
  );

}

add_action( 'init', 'create_films' );
```

And this is the [documentation.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Comment: `rewrite => array('with_front' => false);` [Read More About CPT Rewrites](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments)

Comment: Hmm, I've added `'rewrite'=> array( 'with_front' => false )` but it's still appearing. I've also refreshed the permalinks settings.

Comment: [same question with solution here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/125888/4771).

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Custom Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/) plugin for a while and works ok.