# Redirect permalinks after creating custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, redirect

I'm in the process of reorganizing a website with many posts (~30.000) a part of which have to be migrated to a new custom post type. Since the custom posts have an added slug to the permalink, is there a way to redirect all the requests to the old links like:

`www.example.com/some-interesting-article`

to

`www.example.com/new-post-type/some-interesting-article`

?

Comment: Please make sure you search for an answer before you ask a question - it's been answered on WPSE before - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125886/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type

Comment: Isn't that question asking the opposite of what I need?

Comment: Did you figure this out? Same issue here.