# Rewrite url for custom post type not working

Tags: php

I have a Custom Post Type and i want to rewrite the URL. nothing is working though. This is the adress i have now /?portfolio=adidas. When I rewrite the numerous ways i tried i always get this instead: feeds/active/ which seems to be a template for blogs in my theme.

I think this can be due to me using the wp rss aggregator to pull rss feeds, who i call with a shortcode in my custom post, but seems to be stored somehow with the url Feeds/post_slug, and this is where i get directed.

How can I change this? Tried pretty much every plugin on the market and all the code snippets i can found.. The custom post type is registered in my theme, and not in the functions. This is the code for that:

```
$args = array(
"singular_label"                => __("Portfolio Category", "swiftframework"), 
'public'                        => true,
'hierarchical'                  => true,
'show_ui'                       => true,
'show_in_nav_menus'             => false,
'args'                          => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'','with_front'=>false),
'query_var'                     => true
);

register_taxonomy( 'portfolio-category', 'portfolio', $args );


add_action('init', 'portfolio_register');  

function portfolio_register() {  

$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Portfolio', 'post type general name', "swiftframework"),
    'singular_name' => _x('Portfolio Item', 'post type singular name', "swiftframework"),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'portfolio item', "swiftframework"),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Portfolio Item', "swiftframework"),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Portfolio Item', "swiftframework"),
    'new_item' => __('New Portfolio Item', "swiftframework"),
    'view_item' => __('View Portfolio Item', "swiftframework"),
    'search_items' => __('Search Portfolio', "swiftframework"),
    'not_found' =>  __('No portfolio items have been added yet', "swiftframework"),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash', "swiftframework"),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''

);

$args = array(  
    'labels' => $labels,  
    'public' => true,  
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-image',
'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'','with_front'=>false),
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'taxonomies' => array('portfolio-category')

   );  

register_post_type( 'portfolio' , $args );  
}  

add_filter("manage_edit-portfolio_columns", "portfolio_edit_columns");   

function portfolio_edit_columns($columns){  
    $columns = array(  
        "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",  
        "title" => "Portfolio Item",
        "description" => "Description",
        "portfolio-category" => "Categories"  
    );  

    return $columns;  
   }  

   add_action("manage_posts_custom_column",  "portfolio_custom_columns"); 

   function portfolio_custom_columns($column){  
    global $post;  
    switch ($column)  
    {  
        case "description":  
            the_excerpt();  
            break;
        case "portfolio-category":
            echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'portfolio-category', '', ',,'');
            break;
    }  
}
```

Comment: You are wrong, the rewrite argument it is working but if you set it to an empty string, the default value will be used. If you want to remove the post-type slug from the URL you have to set the rewrite argument to `'/'`. Also, you must know that Wordpress doesn't include custom post types if the post-type slug it is not present in the URL. To include them you have to hook into the `pre_get_post` action hook. You have [instructions in this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125886/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type/144356#144356).

Comment: Appreciate the answer. Tried it, but I get the same result. Instead of /?portfolio=adidas it redirects to /feeds/adidas.

Comment: You should provide more details about when you are redirected. Remember to flush the rewrite rules after changes in them.

Comment: I updated my question a little bit, unsure how to provide more details. I did of course save permalinks, thanks for the reminder though.